# htaccess and Mod_rewrite in subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

In my htaccess I have it set to rewrite URL's so really the query string doesn't show up (pretty url's) but it seems if the site is placed in a subdomain, it brings up a blank page vice going to the correct page.  Does subdomains affect the way this works or is it another issue?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^documents/([^/]+)/?$ documents.php?p=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Converting folder/documents.php?p=value to www.mywebsite.com/folder/documents/VARIABLE (removing .php?p=value)

subdomain equivalent:
subdomain.mywebsite.com/folder/documents/VARIABLE

Answer (score 0):

Try turning `MultiViews` option off by using this code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^documents/([^/]+)/?$ documents.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.